# Volley AppController class object returning null

Tags: java, android, networking, android-volley

I am making an app that makes a `JsonObjectRequest` and retrieves a JSON data from an URL using the Volley Networking Library for android.

**AppController.java**

```
public class AppController extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance(){
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){
        if(mRequestQueue == null){
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
}
```

**Method in MainActivity.class**

```
private void makeJSONObjectRequest() {

        showDialog();

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                urlJsonObj, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                try {

                    //Parsing JSON Object response
                    String name = response.getString("name");
                    String email = response.getString("email");
                    JSONObject phone = response.getJSONObject("phone");
                    String home = phone.getString("home");
                    String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");

                    jsonResponse = "";
                    jsonResponse += "Name: " + name + "\n\n";
                    jsonResponse += "Email: " + email + "\n\n";
                    jsonResponse += "Home: " + home + "\n\n";
                    jsonResponse += "Mobile: " + mobile + "\n\n";

                    txtResponse.setTag(jsonResponse);

                }

                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                hideDialog();
            }
        },

        new ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG+"Error:"+ volleyError.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        });

        /*THE ERROR OCCURS HERE! */
        //adding request to the RequestQueue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }
```

It gives the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.h8pathak.volleyjson.AppController.addToRequestQueue(com.android.volley.Request)' on a null object reference
```

How can I rectify this code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `AppController class` needs to extend Application class instead of the AppCompatActivity class.

And remember to update your Manifest as well. ie. Add this class in your AndroidManifest.xml using name attribute for `<application>` tag.

```
<application
        android:name=".AppController"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

i think you should create the "AppController" like this :

```
public class AppController {

    private static AppController mInstance;

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static Context mCtx;

    private AppController(Context context){
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new AppController(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(@NonNull final Request<T> request) {
        getRequestQueue().add(request);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueueWithTag(@NonNull final Request<T> request, String tag) {
        request.setTag(tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(request);
    }
}
```

and the MainActivity.class

```
//adding request to the RequestQueue
AppController.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't use an `Activity` like a Singleton. An `Activity` is a screen of your app and it could be in different states during the usage of your app. You are also leaking it, since you keep a static reference to it. For your purpose, if you need a Context, extend `Application` instead of `AppCompatActivity`, and register it in your Manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you forget to initialize the `RequestQueue` Object. You need to initialize the `RequestQueue` inside the `onCreate` method, like you can see in the example:
(Else when you call `request.add(jsonObjectRequest)` the application will try to reference the `null` object)

```
RequestQueue request;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //request qwe
    request= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
}
```